# How to send elasticsearch bulk request to amazon sqs queue

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-sqs

I am using `org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest` to send over amazon sqs standard queue.

I am able to send the request to sqs queue, and I could see the bulk requests message in the queue through the command line.

When I am trying to receive the message and parsing it back using org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest getting parsing exception

Here is the producer

```
public void sendMessage(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        long startIndex = 0;
        long batchSize = queueConfiguration.getBatchSize();
        String index = getIndex();
        int count = 1;
        log.info("Batch size is : " + batchSize);
        while(true){
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<Order> orderList = serviceImpl.fetchBatch(startIndex, batchSize);

            BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
            for (Order order : orderList) {
                Map<String, Object> documentMapper = mapper.convertValue(order, Map.class);
                IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(index).source(documentMapper);
                indexRequest.id(count + "");
                count++;
                bulkRequest.add(indexRequest);
            }

            try{
                SendMessageRequest messageRequest = new SendMessageRequest()
                        .withQueueUrl(queueConfiguration.getSqsEndPointUrl())
                        .withMessageBody(mapper.writeValueAsString(bulkRequest))
                        .withDelaySeconds(10);
                amazonSQS.sendMessage(messageRequest);
            } catch (Exception ex){
                log.error("Exception encountered while putting orderlist in queue : " + ex);
            }

            if(orderList.size() < batchSize){
                break;
            }
            startIndex = startIndex + batchSize;
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            log.info("Time taken to fetch : " + startIndex + " is : " + (endTime - startTime) + "ms");
        }
    }
```

and consumer is

```
@SqsListener(value = "queue-name")
    public void indexOrders(String message) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try{
            BulkRequest bulkRequest = mapper.readValue(message, BulkRequest.class);
            client.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            log.error("Exception while parsing bulk request" , ex);
        }
        log.info(message);

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Time taken to process message is : " + (endTime - startTime));
    }
```

I am getting below exception, check in the consumer code at (BulkRequest bulkRequest = mapper.readValue(message, BulkRequest.class);) line
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "description" (class org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "refreshPolicy", "parentTask"])`

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why the extra description field is getting added?